# sendling log4j logs in stdout to a file in an openshift container

Tags: java, log4j, openshift, stdout

I am trying to change the log4j properties from stdout to a file and used the below format , but it did not make any difference.I am still getting the logs in stdout not in file.  I am not sure if i missed something.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/POD_LOG.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Please let me know if i missed something..

Comment: ignoring the log4j question here, why do you want to write them to a file?  persisting data to a container is an anti-pattern.  by logging to stdout, you should have a logging solution saving the logs appropriately using ClusterLogging to ClusterLogForwarder

Comment: I am trying to write them to a file so that it can be send to the fluentd container and then see the logs in splunk